# WPF Button to CheckBoxTemplate

Tags: wpf

I am trying to give checkBox controltemplate to Button seeing an example in WPF Unleashed Text Book.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttoncheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
            <Rectangle Width="20"  Height="20" x:Name="outerCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5">
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle  Width="10" Height="10" x:Name="InnerCircle">                    
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid> 
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="outerCircle" Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="InnerCircle" Property="Fill" Value="Orange"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

 <Button Template="{StaticResource buttoncheckBox}" Margin="10" Padding="10"/>
```

Here When I hover mouse or press it is not triggering events everywhere but only when I click on the border it is triggering.
When I use textbook example it is working anywhere what is difference I don't understand.

Comment: Have you seen this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Grid you are using has no Background.

This is to fix your issue:

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttoncheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" Width="20" Height="20">
.....
```

You will have to check to see how you can make this code work with different resolutions. Now it seems to be only for 20x20.

Comment: Thanks.Shall you say how to make it work for different resolutions.As first step I kept  width and height hard coded values

Comment: @NAGASREE Pleae check my answer. I updated it to show you how to properly template the button. This will behave exactly like a default `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

The only element that is currently available for hit test is the `Rectangle.Stroke` (the small border or line) When you interact with that thin line you will recognize that it will behave as you would expect. To make the whole `Rectangle` hit test visible you have to set the `Rectangle.Fill` property of both `Rectangles`:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Transparent" />
```

To allow the `Button` to resize properly use a `Border`. To enable the `Button` to display content like an icon or label text you need to add a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttoncheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Border x:Name="outerCircle" 
          Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" 
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
    <Grid>
      <Rectangle x:Name="InnerCircle" />
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver"
             Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="outerCircle"
              Property="BorderBrush"
              Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}">
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"
             Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="InnerCircle"
              Property="Fill"
              Value="Orange">
      </Setter>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and use it like this:

```
<Button Background="Transparent" 
        Width="80" Height="80" 
        Padding="5" 
        Template="{StaticResource buttoncheckBox}"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="0.5"
        Content="Label Text" />
```

Modify `Button.Padding` to resize the inner `Rectangle`.

Comment: Hi you kept contentPresenter in the template but why Label Text is not visible when I use it? You didn't used Fill="Transparent" still it is handling mouseHover.Is it because of TemplateBinding?

Comment: @NAGASREE The `Border` is handling the mouse events. `Border.Backgroud` is bound to the templated parent's `Button.Background`. The `Button.Background` is `Transparent`. The label text is there. Just increase `Button.Width` and `Button.Height` and you can read it. I set both to '80'. Or use e.g. 80x30. Or use a smaller `Button.FontSize`. You can modify `Button.Padding` to resize the inner `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you don't set a `Background` for a control or a panel such as the `Grid`, the area is considered to belong to the parent window and that's why no mouse events get raised.

If you don't want any actual background you should still set the `Background` property of the `Grid` to `Transparent` for the mouse movements and the clicks to be registered.

You don't need to specify a fixed size for the `Grid` though. Just setting the `Background` should be enough:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttoncheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        ...
```